# How to verify that signed transaction, is correctly signed?

Tags: polkadot-js, javascript

I want to decode and check if the given hex data for the transaction is valid and signed correctly.

The flowing is how I currently construct the transaction and convert it to hexadecimal format.

```js
    let addProxy = api.tx.proxy.addProxy(PROXY, 'Any', 0);
    let remark = api.tx.system.remark("Test");

    let tx = api.tx.utility.batch([
        addProxy,
        remark,
    ]);
    let singedTx = await tx.signAsync(pair);
    let signedTxHex = singedTx.toHex()
    
    console.log("Signed TX", signedTxHex);
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to do it in PolkadotJS?
Otherwise you can use the tool Subkey:
https://docs.substrate.io/reference/command-line-tools/subkey/
with the command:

```
subkey verify <your-signedTxHex> <pair.address>
```

Answer (score 1):

As Jaco explained in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/polkadot-js/api/issues/3106#issuecomment-766916887), you can't just verify the signature of a transaction with polkadot.js.

Alex's answer is a good alternative by using  the tool Subkey.

However, if instead of transactions, you want to verify just messages, you can do that with the [util-crypto package](https://github.com/polkadot-js/common/tree/master/packages/util-crypto) of polkadot.js. Here you have [the documentation for it](https://polkadot.js.org/docs/util-crypto/examples/verify-signature).